# Agregar datos a un objeto Entry con informacion de una lista global

Tags: python, lista, tkinter

Estoy intentando llenar una lista con informacion obtenida desde una funcion que recibe datos de un  puerto serial, para despues mostrar los datos en objetos de tipo Entry.

He intentado declarando una lista global para insertar los datos desde dentro de la funcion, y despues se modifiquen en el textvariable pero no me actualiza los valores en los Entry.

como puedo hacer que los Entry se actualicen con los nuevos valores de la lista?

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry
import tkinter as tk
import serial
import re

window = Tk()
window.title("Matrix")
window.geometry("650x500")
window.resizable(False, False)

#abrir el puerto serial
s = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)

#declaro la variable de tipo Lista global
lista = [5,10,15]

Label(window, text="De clic en el boton y comience a leer los datos").place(x=50, y=30, width=300, height=30)

def leer_datos():
    global lista
    lista = []
    i = 1

    #ciclo while para para recibir los datos del tensiometro
    while i<=3:
        res = s.read(size=10).decode()
        patron = r'\b\d+.\d+\b'
        coincidencias = re.findall(patron, res)

        #Si no hay un dispositivo serial, usar la siguiente linea y comentar las 3 anteriores
        #coincidencias = input("Dato: ")
        filas = (float(x) for x in coincidencias)

        #ciclo para escribir el dato recibido en el libro
        for fila in filas:
            lista.insert(len(lista), fila)
        window.update()
        i += 1

#obtener valores de la lista
valor1 = lista[0]
valor2 = lista[1]
valor3 = lista[2]
valor1_1 = tk.StringVar(value=valor1)
valor1_2 = tk.StringVar(value=valor2)
valor1_3 = tk.StringVar(value=valor3)

# objetos Entry        
entry1 = Entry(window, textvariable=valor1_1)
entry1.place(x=150, y=70, width=100, height=20)

entry2 = Entry(window, textvariable=valor1_2)
entry2.place(x=150, y=90, width=100, height=20)

entry3 = Entry(window, textvariable=valor1_3)
entry3.place(x=150, y=110, width=100, height=20)


# boton para leer los datos
buton = Button(window,text="Leer Datos", command=leer_datos)
buton.place(x=300,y=90,width=150, height=20)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el método `set` de los StringVars asociados a los entrys. El método `set` acepta de argumento un objeto que se pueda convertir a cadena, el cual será  el nuevo valor de todos los widgets asociados a dicho StringVar. En tu caso `valor1_1` cambiaría el primer entry y asi sucesivamente.

A diferencia de usar insert y delete, esta forma requiere menos lineas de código y funciona incluso si el entry está en un estado (state) que no es "normal".

```
def leer_datos():
    global lista
    lista = [9,13,22]
    valor1_1.set(lista[0])
    valor1_2.set(lista[1])
    valor1_3.set(lista[2])
    window.update()
```

Consejo: Usa nombres de variables que dejen claro que contienen. Por ejemplo usa `valor_dolar`, `valor_peso` y `valor_euro`, en lugar de `valor1_1`, `valor1_2` y `valor1_3`. De este modo tu código será más claro y fácil de leer.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar los métodos `delete()` e `insert()` para actualizar el valor de tus `Entry`

Modifiqué tu código para hacer un simple ejemplo de como actualizar los valores para no hacer todo lo de comunicación serial que ya tienes funcionando

Para borrar todo lo que viene en el `Entry` puedes utilizar `delete(0, 'end')` y para insertar un nuevo valor utilizas el segundo parámetro de `insert()`

Te dejo el ejemplo funcionando

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry
import tkinter as tk
import re

window = Tk()
window.title("Matrix")
window.geometry("650x500")
window.resizable(False, False)

#declaro la variable de tipo Lista global
lista = [5,10,15]

Label(window, text="De clic en el boton y comience a leer los datos").place(x=50, y=30, width=300, height=30)

def leer_datos():
    global lista
    lista = [9,13,22]
    entry1.delete(0, 'end')
    entry2.delete(0, 'end')
    entry3.delete(0, 'end')
    entry1.insert(0, lista[0])
    entry2.insert(0, lista[1])
    entry3.insert(0, lista[2])
    window.update()

#obtener valores de la lista
valor1 = lista[0]
valor2 = lista[1]
valor3 = lista[2]
valor1_1 = tk.StringVar(value=valor1)
valor1_2 = tk.StringVar(value=valor2)
valor1_3 = tk.StringVar(value=valor3)

# objetos Entry        
entry1 = Entry(window, textvariable=valor1_1)
entry1.place(x=150, y=70, width=100, height=20)

entry2 = Entry(window, textvariable=valor1_2)
entry2.place(x=150, y=90, width=100, height=20)

entry3 = Entry(window, textvariable=valor1_3)
entry3.place(x=150, y=110, width=100, height=20)


# boton para leer los datos
buton = Button(window,text="Leer Datos", command=leer_datos)
buton.place(x=300,y=90,width=150, height=20)

window.mainloop()
```

Podrías poner esta sección de tu código adentro de tu función antes de user `delete()` e `insert()`

```
#obtener valores de la lista
valor1 = lista[0]
valor2 = lista[1]
valor3 = lista[2]
valor1_1 = tk.StringVar(value=valor1)
valor1_2 = tk.StringVar(value=valor2)
valor1_3 = tk.StringVar(value=valor3)
```

Comment: Es importante resaltar que delete e insert solo funcionan cuando el estado (state) del entry es "normal".